# Auto-trim functionality in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs, autocad

Is there a way to implement auto-trim functionality similar to what they have in AutoCAD?

I have an SVG shape added to my fabric.js canvas using fabric.loadSVGfromString(). Then I add a circle over it using new fabric.Circle() and I need to be able to auto-trim the internal lines because I only need to have the outline of the shapes.

[Shapes before auto-trim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AghEg.png)

From the above shapes I need the auto trim to get the shape below:

[Shape after auto-trim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nrMq.png)

Do you have any idea if that is possible or what I should try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IoanaB: when converting CAD to SVG you'll usually lose any shape context – so an object is basically converted to a group of disconnected single line/path elements. In other words: CAD and SVG are completely different – you can't expect any svg library to rebuild proper compound shapes from CADs line cluster approach. However you might find CAD applications with smarter svg conversions (retaining object structures but producing cleaner svg equivalents). In fact you can do something similar in paper.js provided you objects are paths (Boolean path operations like subtract, unite etc)